# If the value of the nested input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested-forms

I'm trying to check a value (:cat) form a nested input. If this value is one, display something, else dispay nothing

```
<%= f.simple_fields_for :elements do |element| %>
  <%- if element.cat == 1 %>
    <%= render 'elements/element_fields', f: element %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I tried that, but is not working. I have the error (undefined method `cat'). Do you have an idea to solve that ?

Comment: You're calling the method 'cat' on an object (element) that doesn't respond to cat. What attribute are you trying to check? Is cat something that's entered in the form or an attribute of the model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ask not form object but original one

```
if element.object.cat == 1
```